# How can I make a select in django using a multi-database?

Tags: django, multi-database

I 'm using multi-database, and I try:

```
        cursor = connection.cursor().using(profile.dbname)
        cursor.execute('select id_retorno from prc_sequenciadora(' + str(profile.idempresa) + ', "VENDA_PEDIDO", "IDVENDA_PEDIDO", 0, 0)')# calls PROCEDURE named LOG_MESSAGE which resides in MY_UTIL Package
        cursor.fetchall()
```

But this error appears:

AttributeError at /comerx/pedidos/novo/
'Cursor' object has no attribute 'using'

Here is traceback: http://pastebin.com/CD7B8BxJ

Thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should import django.db.connections - which is a dictionary-like object that allows you to retrieve a specific database connection by its alias. Then you should use its appropriate cursor. I believe there is no "using" method for the Cursor object (that is what the error message says).

So, we have:

```
from django.db import connections
my_db_alias = profile.dbname #in your situation
cursor = connections[my_db_alias].cursor()
# Your code goes here...
```

For more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: if you need more info on how to connect multiple database see this link https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/tutorial-using-djangos-multiple-database-support-477#multi-database-setup